# SQL Server Dynamic SQL Execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic SQL query

```
DECLARE @ItemAreaCode NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'A062',
        @SQLStringDropTable NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQLStringDropTable= 'DROP TABLE' + ' ' +
                         '[@ItemAreaCode].[ChangedRMAllocation]'

PRINT @ItemAreaCode

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStringDropTable , N'@ItemAreaCode NVARCHAR(MAX)', @ItemAreaCode;
```

But when I execute this, I get this error:

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
>   Cannot drop the table '@ItemAreaCode.ChangedRMAllocation', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

And the printed query is..

```
DROP TABLE [@ItemAreaCode].[ChangedRMAllocation];
```

What I need is:

```
DROP TABLE [A062].[ChangedRMAllocation];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to expand the variable:

```
DECLARE @ItemAreaCode sysname = 'A062',
    @SQLStringDropTable NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQLStringDropTable = 
    'DROP TABLE ' + quotename(@ItemAreaCode) + '.[ChangedRMAllocation]';
EXEC (@SQLStringDropTable);
```

Comment: If the parameter is not a table name, Can I use a query like mine in the question?

Comment: It's better to avoid dynamic SQL if you can. Parameterized queries are almost always preferred.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting you parameter as a string within the dynamic SQL.
`@ItemAreaCode` should not be included.

This should work :

```
DECLARE @ItemAreaCode NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'A062',
@SQLStringDropTable NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @SQLStringDropTable= 'DROP TABLE' + ' [' 
                            + @ItemAreaCode +  '].[ChangedRMAllocation]'

    PRINT @ItemAreaCode
    EXEC (@SQLStringDropTable);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Agree that the variable should be expanded in the string (although better with `quotename`), but why do you still pass it as a parameter to `sp_executesql` ?

Comment: @Andomar I need to write a query preventing sql injection here. That's why I used sp_executesql and pass parameters in to it. If this answer is not the right way how to do that

Comment: @tarzanbappa: This answer is vulnerable to SQL injection through `@ItemAreaCode = ']; drop database importantstuff; --'` for example. You can't pass table names as parameters. Use `quotename` to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @ItemAreaCode NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'A062'
    ,@SQLStringDropTable NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQLStringDropTable = 'DROP TABLE [' + @ItemAreaCode + '].[ChangedRMAllocation]'

EXEC (@SQLStringDropTable)
```